# Http request via one network interface

Tags: java, rest, network-programming

I would like to call HTTP request for rest webservice only on selected network interface.

Any advice on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008781/is-it-possible-to-specify-which-network-interface-for-a-jvm-or-ide-to-use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that you can define network interface in url like this :

```
192.168.1.122%eth0
```

It's working in Ubuntu and I hope that it works in different systems too.

Answer (score 1):

This is more or less out of the control of your Java program.

It's up to the OS to decide where to send the packets. It'll send the packets on the interface that's configured to have a route to the destination IP - or send it on the default route. So, you have to just make sure you've configured your OS properly to route the IP packets where you want them, and it'll only send them on that interface.

Comment: Hmm so you think that solution is in routing table in OS. It was my first idea too, but I would like to create more abstract app. I found http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html but it seems that there is now way how to specify network interface in http request. I dont know how sockets work at Java. Iam Java beginner.

Comment: @Petr Velký yes. the solution is the OS routing table. The NetworkInterface class has nothing to do with HTTP requests, nor how to specify a network interface for your IP packets. Receiving requests is another matter though, there's APIs for listening to incoming connections on a partiular IP address(which is normally bound to only one network interface).