# Binding originating request to an IP address in java

Tags: java, sockets, proxy

My server has multiple IP address, we are required to write code in such a manner that all request being sent to another server must originate from different IP's at different times.

We are using `url.openStream()` in java, is this possible?

Comment: What about a [proxy](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)?

Comment: Why? What's the reason for this strange requirement?

Comment: possible related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786674/http-request-via-one-network-interface