# java how to specify the right IP-address that a program should connect from

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ip

I have a java program(swing) that connects to a remote host. This program was working just fine on my windows 7 box. However, after I installed VirtualBox, it failed to connect to the remote box; On investigation we found it started "binding" itself to the VirtualBox IP address rather than the "Wireless LAN Adapter wireless network connection" that it previously did.

I wrote a test program which connected to the same remote host and this program worked fine despite Virtual Box.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
    Socket testSock = new Socket("10.86.149.206", 7547);
    System.out.println("connected!");
}
```

Question : How do I tell the java swing program which IP it should use as the source IP address ?

for what it's worth, we use jdk 1.6

**UPDATE** : 
Eventually, I had to uninstall VirtualBox in order to get the Java Swing program to connect to the remote host :-(

**UPDATE 2** : 
I was wondering if I could specify a system property so the java program would know what to do.

**UPDATE 3**: 
in case anyone was wondering, I don't have access to the swing program's source code. I would like to regulate its behavior externally, if possible.**

Comment: yes and no. I can get the swing program to connect to remote host but ONLY by uninstalling virtualbox. I would like to retain virtualbox and still run the java program. I was wondering if I could specify a system property so the java program would know what to do.

Answer (score 2):

The Socket contructor supports a four parameter version where you can specify the local address and port as well. See [java.net.Socket](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#Socket%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20java.net.InetAddress,%20int%29) for details.

Comment: I don't have access to code. Also, I believe that the swing program uses a http client library to talk to the remote host. Any thoughts ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be essentially the same question: [Is it possible to specify which network interface for a JVM ( or IDE ) to use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008781/is-it-possible-to-specify-which-network-interface-for-a-jvm-or-ide-to-use)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use specific local IP address to connect to server you should call bind method and as a parameter pass this address.