# HttpURLConnection & Using A Specific Network Adapter

Tags: java, network-programming, httpurlconnection

I'd like to use the Java class [HttpURLConnection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/net/HttpURLConnection.html) to connect to a particular device on a (local network). I have need to use a specific network adapter because the machine that will be running my program has 2 network adapters installed. One adapter is on a wider company network and is dynamically assigned an IP whilst the second is a network local to the machine and has a static IP. It is this second local network to which I want to restrict my program to.

Using HttpURLConnection is convenient because it relieves me of having to parse the server response etc and get straight at the data I need instead of doing something like [this](http://lj4newbies.blogspot.com/2007/07/using-httpurlconnection.html). However because I need to restrict my HTTP requests to a specific network adapter I can't be 100% sure that my HTTP requests are sent ONLY via the desired adapter. Am I correct in my understanding of how HttpURLConnection works i.e. it relies on the operating system to select the appropriate network adapter to use?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008781/is-it-possible-to-specify-which-network-interface-for-a-jvm-or-ide-to-use

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With plain Java you will only be able to bind a [Socket](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html) to a selected [NetworkInterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html).

If you need HTTP protocol support with ability to control which network interface to connect from you'll need to use [Apache HTTP Client](http://hc.apache.org/).

You'll need to provide a `ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS` parameter to it, see details here: http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html.

UPDATE:

Since 4.3 ConnRoutePNames is deprecated, please use [RequestConfig](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html) and its [RequestConfig.Builder](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.Builder.html) instead.

Comment: Thanks! Not Qwe any more :)